# Are memory mapped registers separate registers on the bus?

Tags: arm, cpu-registers, memory-mapping

I will use the `TM4C123` Arm Microcontroller/Board as an example.

Most of it's I/O registers are memory mapped so you can get/set their values using
regular memory load/store instructions.

My questions is, is there some type of register outside of cpu somewhere on the bus which is mapped to memory and you read/write to it using the memory region essentially having duplicate values one on the register and on memory, or the memory IS the register itself?

Comment: There is CPU and there are peripheral blocks (aka IP blocks/IP core) connected to that CPU via 'memory' bus (eg AXI bus, or whatever that particular CPU has). Reading/writing to addresses that these IP blocks are hardware connected is a way to interact with these blocks. From CPU point of view these IP blocks are 'memory mapped'. CPU does not have 'separate registers' to access them. IP blocks have 'interface registers' that CPU could read/write by reading/writing memory values. But 'CPU registers' and 'IP blocks registers' are totally different things.

Comment: so my question was, are `IP blocks registers` literally just part of memory address space, or they are actual registers outside of cpu which communicate using the memory as a bridge?

Comment: Both or neither depending on your definitions... IP blocks are part of memory address space and IP block registers are actual registers from IP block point of view (from CPU side they are just another words in memory). Eg 'CPU registers' != 'IP block registers' though both have 'registers' in name.

Comment: Right i'm just trying to confirm there is an actual register involved outside the cpu, i.e `i/o registers` isn't just refereeing to literally a chunk of memory and there is nothing else involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many buses even in an MCU.  Bus after bus after bus splitting off like branches in a tree. (sometimes even merging unlike a tree).

It may predate the intel/motorola battle but certainly in that time frame you had segmented vs flat addressing and you had I/O mapped I/O vs memory mapped I/O, since motorola (and others) did not have a separate I/O bus (well one extra...address...signal).

Look at the arm architecture documents and the chip documentation (arm makes IP not chips).  You have load and store instructions that operate on addresses.  The documentation for the chip (and to some extent ARM provides rules for the cortex-m address space) provides a long list of addresses for things.  As a programmer you simply line up the address you do loads and stores with and the right instructions.

Someones marketing may still carry about terms like memory mapped I/O, because intel x86 still exists (how????), some folks will continue to carry those terms.  As a programmer, they are number one just bits that go into registers, and for single instructions here and there those bits are addresses.  If you want to add adjectives to that, go for it.

If the address you are using based on the chip and core documentation is pointing at an sram, then that is a read or write of memory.  If it is a flash address, then that is the flash.  The uart, the uart.  timer 5, then timer 5 control and status registers.  Etc...

There are addresses in these mcus that point at two or three things, but not at the same time.  (address 0x00000000 and some number of kbytes after that).  But, again, not at the same time.  And this overlap at least in many of these cortex-m mcus, these special address spaces are not going to overlap "memory" and peripherals (I/O).  But instead places where you can boot the chip and run some code.  With these cortex-ms I do not think you can even use the sort of mmu to mix these spaces.  Yes definitely in full sized arms and other architectures you can use a fully blow mcu to mix up the address spaces and have a virtual address space that lands on a physical address space of a different type.

Comment: wow this was a lot of info, thanks. you mentioned `Memory is memory, you dont send a write to a control register also to a memory, nor through the normal memory space. If you look at the memory map, the sram blocks are that address space.`. So then the address space IS the actual "register" itself and not a bridge? Then why is it called"memory mapping", there is no mapping going on. Also I know this is a big topic and it differs from platform to platform as said by this post: https://superuser.com/a/695508 , i.e the memory might be the "register" itself, or it could be a bridge.

Comment: right, but how does the data within that address space get used? say the data is needed by a printer, would the printer copy that data to its internal register OR the memory IS acting as the register itself? I think the answer is "it depends". some may use the memory directly, some may copy it to internal registers, am I right?

Comment: ok what if we use the original Arm board as the example, I/O registers, are you saying they are not actually registers then? it's just memory?

Comment: Sorry I was referring to `TM4C123` in my original question. This board has many I/O registers that are memory mapped. I still don't get what that means then. What are they mapped to? mapped to another register? mapped to nothing and it's all just memory address space?

Comment: so that address region gets used as is, it's not mapped to anything. Then it's not really a "register", it is just sram, I think of registers as flip-flops inside a cpu which get used for arithmetic calculation. `Register 1` in your above example is not a register, it's sram, it's just memory, why do they call it a register.

Comment: So then it's an actual register which happens to have an address similar to a memory address?

Comment: I see, so the term "memory mapped" doesn't mean the address space is mapped to some other register. It means that region **IS** a register which happens to share an address with the memory address space.

Comment: Thanks a lot. so why don't they give these I/O registers names like regular CPU registers such as `r0`, `r1` etc. Why do they have to have an address similar to memory? I guess it just makes the design and decoding easier?

Comment: They are all separate but they all fall within the "memory address space". wether its sram or an I/O register they all have a "memory address", that's what the term is saying. it all makes sense now.

Comment: the term "memory" map is only to distinguish it from the term I/O map in the minds of folks that seem to think that matters.   It defines a bus or set of control signals as to what "address space" the individual itemms land in (flash, sram, peripherals, processor control registers).  In the case of this arm you have three buses, icode, dcode and system.   I suspect a reason for continuing to use the term memory map is to avoid the stigma of I/O mapped I/O.  Not that I/O mapped I/O was ever bad (and at least on the 8088/86 was not a separate bus from memory).

Comment: the take away here is to stop trying to put meaning in to these terms, they are mostly vague or incorrect at best, but we have been using them for so long that people just know what they mean.  they dont mean what the words say, you internally translate them to what they really mean.  which in this case is just an address map for the system.